# php string gets truncated when retried from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

the original string is around 9000+ characters.
but after mysql_fetch_object();

the $obj->attr only have 8000+ characters, with all the characters at the end of the string truncated. Is it because the string is too long?

Comment: what's the type of your field in the db?Are you sure that in the db it's stored correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem with your database design. Compare the string in the database to the string on the screen, if they match there's a problem when saving the data, if not, then you might want to supply us with your PHP+SQL code in order to see if there lies a problem.